# Job Schedule Library in a Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a scheduler library which can perform a simple task of invoking other REST APIs at a specific time of a day. Please advise on which is a good library to use in a Spring Boot project. I am basically looking for something which logs job config information to DB automatically and has a UI interface to check the status of jobs (preferable but not mandatory).

I did come across this but as I have no prior experience with any of them but Quartz so I am not able to make the call: http://blog.dreamcss.com/tools/java-based-job-scheduler/

**Note**: I did use Quartz in my previous project but I ran into multiple issue with it as it seems to have issues with not logging job related info to DB. Specifically it would not log proper info into DB about last run time and whether the last job run completed successfully or not. Also, I have seen that the Jobs in Quartz gets blocked if the previous job takes longer to complete.

Answer (score 1):

In spring boot you have an embedded simple engine for scheduling.

Use @Scheduled annotation in your @Component for example.
And don't remember to enable scheduling by using @EnableScheduling annotation.

You can read more about this topic in this article [spring.io link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a Trigger you can calculate the next execution time on the fly.

Something like this should do the trick (adapted from the Javadoc for @EnableScheduling):

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyAppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        myBean().getSchedule();
                    }
                },
                new Trigger() {
                    @Override public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                        Calendar nextExecutionTime =  new GregorianCalendar();
                        Date lastActualExecutionTime = triggerContext.lastActualExecutionTime();
                        nextExecutionTime.setTime(lastActualExecutionTime != null ? lastActualExecutionTime : new Date());
                        nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, env.getProperty("myRate", Integer.class)); //you can get the value from wherever you want
                        return nextExecutionTime.getTime();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```